# How to get iframe content height in mobile/web mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

How to make iframe responsive (change height based on it's content) during the resizing of the parent window (mobile mode and web mode).

In my code  I try to get the height in the resize() of parent window the returned height always is mobile mode only.

```
<script>

    $(window).resize(function () {
        alert($('iframe').contents().height()); // return the mobile mode only
        $('iframe').height($('iframe').contents().height());            
    });


</script>
```

Comment: `the returned height always is mobile mode only` not sure I understand what unit **mobile mode only** is measured in

Comment: Can you perhaps show us the source of the `iframe` you're working with?

Comment: <div id="contentDiv">
        <iframe id="ChartsIframe" visible="false" runat="server" scrolling="no" 
            style="border: none; width: 100%;"></iframe>
    </div>